# Are two edges parallel even when they do not belong to the same graph?

Tags: graph-theory

Two edges are in different graphs.

$G_1=(V_1,E_1)$

$G_2=(V_1,E_2)$

$E_1 = \{a\}$

$E_2 = \{b\}$

Each end is part of the two graphs in which the edges are.

$V_1 = \{u,v\}$

The edges have the same ends.

$\psi_{G_1}(a)=uv$

$\psi_{G_2}(b)=uv$

Are the edges parallel (by the definition of a 'parallel edge')?

Comment: I don't see how there can be an objectively correct answer to this question. The "right" definition depends on how you plan on using it.

Comment: Care to elaborate on different uses?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It really doesn't make sense in general to say that edges in "different" graphs are parallel.  In your situation, a reasonably correct thing to say is that the graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$ both naturally embed in the graph $G=G_1\cup G_2$ (which is actually a multigraph), and that $E_1$ and $E_2$ are parallel edges in $G$.

Remark: the union $G_1\cup G_2$ is fairly unambiguous, since you have explicitly identified the vertex sets but nothing else.  If you wanted to be a little more explicit, you could write $G_1\cup_{V_1} G_2$ to emphasize that $V_1$ is the common structure being identified.

Comment: I think you meant 'ambiguous'?

Comment: @Marein no, I meant it's unambiguous, at least in this context.  In other contexts it might be necessary to emphasize what's being "glued."

Comment: Ah got it, thanks.